# Scope value receiving update only from one controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button, *box.component.js:*

```
angular.module('box').component('box', {
    templateUrl: 'box.template.html',
    controller: function boxController(mainService, UiService){
        this.addBox = function () {

            //Set box as selected
            var box = mainService.selected;
            var nodesHolder = UiService.getNodesHolder().children;

            //Set custom properties
            box.name = "Box";
            box.id = nodesHolder.length;
            box.parameters = {
              parm1:  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1), 
              parm2:  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1), 
              parm3:  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)

            };
            //Push box into nodes holder array
            nodesHolder.push(box);
        }
    }
});
```

when clicked it creates an object which populates an array, my *list.component.js:* (shown in the view as circles):

```
angular.module('list').component('list', {

    templateUrl: 'list.template.html',

    controller: function nodesController(UiService) {

        this.nodes = UiService.getNodesHolder().children;

        this.selected = function (value) {

            var nodes = UiService.getNodesHolder();

            UiService.selected = nodes.children[value];

        }


    }

});
```

and also displays its name and parameters through *parms-bar.component:*

```
angular.module('parms-bar').component('parmsbar', {
    templateUrl: 'parms-bar.template.html',
    controller: function parmsController(mainService){
        this.selected = mainService.selected;
    }
});
```

The communication between these components is managed by two services. One which detects the selected object, *main.service.js:*

```
angular.module('app').service('mainService', function(){
    var selected = {};

    var service = {
        get selected(){
            return selected;
        },
        set selected(value){
            selected = value;
        }
    }
    return service;
});
```

and one which return the items in the list (the circles), *ui.service.js:*

```
angular.module('app').service('UiService', function(){

    //Nodes-holder
    var nodesHolder = { children: []};

    return {

        getNodesHolder: function () {
            return nodesHolder;
        }
    };
});
```

When I click on a circle I would like to switch to the corresponding object, so display its parameters, but this is not working.It seems that the parameters view only gets updated by the box controller. Maybe something wrong in my `list.component.js`where I'm try to set the circle as selected?

```
 this.selected = function (value) {

            var nodes = UiService.getNodesHolder();

            UiService.selected = nodes.children[value];

        }
```

[Live example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0NW6S3FRk5VjdAYw4s5P?p=preview)

Comment: Messing around with the example (added a `console.log(value)` to selected), no matter which circle you click, the `id` is the same

Comment: @Vasseurth - That's true. Actually in my original project it returns me the right id, it's just not updating the view. I messed up something trying to extrapolate the problem to make an example. I'll try to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point here is to keep the object same, there are two things what I found here,

First, since you are keeping the object same then, when add box function runs the same object is manipulated, that is all the values in the array 
takes the value of the latest modification. So, to counter it I created a new copy of the box object while pushing it to array.

```
nodesHolder.push(angular.copy(box));
```

Second, in list component.js you are not updating mainService.selected so I changed

```
UiService.selected = nodes.children[value];
              to
mainService.selected = nodes.children[value];
```

Now, another problem arises, because of the first solution. Since, I am making a copy of the object, the value that gets set in **mainService.selected** is different than the **previous value** that was in it. So to keep the object same i have created two funtions

```
1. function clearObject(obj){
         // Function that cleans up the keys of the given object 
         // without creating a new object.
   }

2. function copyData(obj) {
       // Function that copies the new object data to selected.
   }
```

Finally, here is the working plunk,
     https://plnkr.co/edit/Tk8YstW83NKwnYtbQZnM?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Actually when u change this into objet model in the ***box.component.js*** file.

```
box = {
  "name": "Box",
  "id": nodesHolder.length,
  "parameters": {
    "parm1":  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1), 
    "parm2":  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1), 
    "parm3":  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
  }
}
```

then the selected circle showing the correct value. please check using `console.log(UiService.selected);` in the ***list.component.js*** file. 
and some minor error in ***list.template.html*** file change into `<div id="list" class="list">` .Actually it is like this in your plnkr `<div id="list"class"list">`. sorry i can proceed this much only i need some time to make it work.

Comment: thanks for helping, but now parameters are not showing at all :(